# White screen of death on navigating from innermost stack screen to outermost stack screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a stack navigator containing tab navigator which contains stack navigator. From the innermost stack screen i am trying to navigate to a screen in outer stack. The innermost stack screen unmounts but the screen in outer stack does not mount and is stuck at white screen of death.

I have already tried logging the result and seen nothing there.

My App.js

```
const profileNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Account: {
      screen: Accountscreen
    },
    Support: {
    screen: Supportscreen
    },
  },
);

const feedNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Feed: {
      screen: Feedscreen
    },
  },
);

const chatNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    chatnews: {
      screen: chatnews
    },

  },

);

const Tabscreen = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    Profile: {
      screen: profileNavigator,
    },
    Feed: {
      screen: feedNavigator,      
    },
    Chat: {
      screen: chatNavigator,
    }
  },
);

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    LoginCheck: {
      screen: LoginCheckScreen
    },
    Login: {
      screen: Loginscreen
    },
    Tabscreen: {
      screen: Tabscreen
    }
  },
  }
);
```

My code in logout screen code:

```
NavigationService.navigate("LoginCheck");
```

NavigationService Code

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';
let _navigator;

function setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef) {
    _navigator = navigatorRef;
}

function navigate(routeName, params) {
    _navigator.dispatch(
        NavigationActions.navigate({
            type: NavigationActions.NAVIGATE,
            routeName,
            params,
        })
    );
}

export default {
    navigate,
    setTopLevelNavigator,
};
```

I expected to navigate to the LoginCheck screen, but instead it unmount the account screen but freezes the app on white screen of death.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you use switch navigator?

Change to the following.

import the headers

```
import {
  ...
  ...
  createAppContainer,
  createStackNavigator,
  createSwitchNavigator,
} from "react-navigation";
```

update the code

```
const profileNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Account: {
      screen: Accountscreen
    },
    Support: {
    screen: Supportscreen
    },
  },
);

const feedNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Feed: {
      screen: Feedscreen
    },
  },
);

const chatNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    chatnews: {
      screen: chatnews
    },

  },

);

const Tabscreen = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    Profile: {
      screen: profileNavigator,
    },
    Feed: {
      screen: feedNavigator,      
    },
    Chat: {
      screen: chatNavigator,
    }
  },
);

const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    LoginCheck: LoginCheckScreen,
    Login: Loginscreen,
    Tabscreen: Tabscreen
  },
  { headerMode: "none", initialRouteName: "PreLoader" }
);

const App = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

export default App; //finally export App
```

When you want to change to login screen use the following code on button click or something else.

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("LoginCheck");
```

Comment: You saved my day. Can you please elaborate on the issue technically ? I wanted to know what was going wrong as stack navigator has been working good in simple snack projects. So just out of curiosity asking this question !!